# ollydbg - two noob questions regarding plugins

Tags: ollydbg

I have the basics of ollydbg covered fairly well but have come up against a brick wall:

1. Cant find referenced text on search, can anyone reccomend plugins to get around this?
2. Plugin directory is referenced in options => directories but on the plugins dropdown i get no options other than bookmarks. Clicked on bookmarks and its empty.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded ollydbg 1.0 and the plugins now appear.